# Azure SQL Server Monitoring/Alerting for Multiple Databases (v12)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-monitoring

What is the best way to monitor a certain metric and alert on it over multiple databases. For example I want to trigger an alert if a database size grows larger than 10 GB.

I know you can select a single database and configure this in Azure Monitor but when there are hundreds this doesn't seem viable.

> My Databases are created with **Azure Resource Management**

Comment: You'll probably need to invest into 3rd party monitoring products like CloudMonix @ http://www.cloudmonix.com for things like templatable metrics and alerts, sophisticated reporting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think PowerShell, specifically the [Get-AzureSqlDatabaseUsages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/get-azuresqldatabaseusages?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) command, is your best friend here. I've done this in the past as a modified "heartbeat". Whereby we also analyzed index fragmentation, and triggered a `REBUILD` if needed.

An example of the PowerShell command from above:

```
C:\> Get-AzureSqlDatabaseUsages -ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName "Database01"
```

This will require that you be authenticated, but that itself is simple enough as well.

You could execute the script on a schedule (i.e. either as a WebJob or a Scheduled Task) and report/notify based on certain metric thresholds.

> EDIT: For v12 databases use the following query (which can be execute programmatically using PowerShell and `sqlcmd.exe`)

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS bigint) * 8192.) AS DatabaseSizeInBytes,
       SUM(CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS bigint) * 8192.) / 1024 / 1024 AS DatabaseSizeInMB,
       SUM(CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS bigint) * 8192.) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS DatabaseSizeInGB
FROM sys.database_files
WHERE type_desc = 'ROWS';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pim, but that powershell command is only viable for resources created in the classic portal. My SQL Databases are created with Azure Resource Management.

Answer (score 0):

After some more delving I found a somewhat satisfactory solution in Azure:

1. Go to Azure Monitor Metric(preview)
2. In my case I was using an sql elastic pool so I added this as Resource with 
   metric "storaged_used"
3. Add splitting by "Database ARM Resource Id" will give you storage used for each
   SQL database in your pool by Resource Id.

Comment: I just discovered this "splitting" option myself. So I googled "Database ARM Resource Id" and this was the only result!